# Syntax for MySQL CALL using PHP $_Session Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Below is my code for my project.

And yes I'm aware that mysql is deprecated.
I would like to stay consistent with my code and not switch to mysqli or PDO.
Does anyone see where my syntax is wrong in the call? Right now it enters the FALSE condition statement so I know it isn't entering my procedure.

```
session_start();

function Login($idb)
{
    global $global_idx;

    if(isset($_SESSION['appRoleNo']))
        {

            $db = @mysql_connect( HOST, USER, PASSWD );

            if( @mysql_select_db( DATABASE, $db ) )
                {
                    $z = "CALL login_ins_upd('".$_SESSION['tool_user']."', '".$_SESSION['fname']."', '".$_SESSION['lname']."', '".$SESSION['email']."', '".$_SESSION['appRoleName']."', $a)";
                    $y = mysql_query($z);

                if ($y === FALSE) {
                    die(mysql_error());
                    }
                    error_log($a);
                }
          }
}
```

"login_ins_upd" is an exising procedure in my database that I have created.
Also, $a is the output from the procedure (before mysql_error() it was always NULL).

Comment: echo out `$z`; does it look correct? If it's returning false, is your `mysql_error()` call printing out anything? And please, don't use `@` to suppress error messages from function calls - you should check the return values and deal with them. Finally, you don't seem to be initializing `$a` anywhere in this function's scope.

Comment: $z echos out as it should. My error_log isn't picking up anything from my $y variable. I set $a=""; before calling login_ins_upd, and in the CALL I updated $a to '$a' to get the output: CALL login_ins_upd('[userID]', '[fname]', '[lname]', '[email@...]', '[role]', '') The square brackets are my content and are outputting correctly. The output of the call is being displayed as '' and will be changed in the procedure to be returned. However there is still no luck here

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that since it is MySQL, the output parameter has to include an '@' symbol. Therefore the output parameter is '@a'.